# Get NullPointerException when using Application class

Tags: android, android-emulator

I want global variables that with highest level in this app so that it doesn't need to be initialize when activity starts every time. I test my application on my physical device, and get nullPointerException. But success in emulator!!
log information:

```
03-15 15:36:54.851: E/AndroidRuntime(21550): 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{panda.com.db/panda.com.db.IndexActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-15 15:36:54.851: E/AndroidRuntime(21550):
at panda.com.db.LittleRabitAssistants.<init>(LittleRabitAssistants.java:83)
03-15 15:36:54.851: E/AndroidRuntime(21550):
at panda.com.db.Global.Init(Global.java:23)
03-15 15:36:54.851: E/AndroidRuntime(21550):
at panda.com.db.IndexActivity.onCreate(IndexActivity.java:38)
```

Code of global class:

```
public class Global extends Application{
    private static LittleRabitAssistants assistants;
    ..
    ..
    public void Init(){
        this.assistantsDB = new DBAdapter(this,null,null);
        this.assistants = new LittleRabitAssistants(this);
        this.initLocaleFromDB();
    }
}

public LittleRabitAssistants(Global globalVariable){
        this.globalVariable=globalVariable;
            ..
        if(globalVariable.getLocaleLanguage().equals("zh-CN")){
            ..
        }else{
            ..
        }   
    }

public class IndexActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test);
        //get global application
        Global globalApplication = (Global)this.getApplication();
        //initialize the Assistants 
        globalApplication.Init();
        pa = globalApplication.getAsisstents();
}
```

However, the most important thing is, this application run successfully in emulator!!!

Comment: give the code at line 83 in LittleRabitAssistants.java

Comment: can you post this line no 38 from IndexActivity.java

Comment: Have you mentioned your application class in android manifest file??like the following 
application tag of your manifest file
android:name="yourpackgename.Global"

Comment: Did you initialize ComponentInfo, It seems that Component Info is not initialised

Comment: Oh!!thank you for you guys!!I see what is the problem. at LittleRabbitAssistants line 83: if(globalVariable.getLocaleLanguage().equals("zh-CN")){} this line runs before initialize the location and language. so it gets a null pointer exception. thank you for helping me!!^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have called the init() method before calling on the super.onCreate()...